# matplotlib: labeling of curves

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

When I create a plot with many curves it would be convenient to be able to label each curve at the right where it ends.

The result of `plt.legend` produces too many similar colors and the legend is overlapping the plot.

As one can see in the example below the use of `plt.legend` is not very effective:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

n=10
x = np.linspace(0,1, n)

for i in range(n):
   y = np.linspace(x[i],x[i], n)
   plt.plot(x, y, label=str(i))
   
plt.legend(loc='upper right')

plt.show()
```

[image]

If possible I would like to have something similar to this plot:

[image]

or this:

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49237522/how-to-annotate-end-of-lines-using-python-and-matplotlib

Have you checked this one out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend the [answer suggested in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49237522/how-to-annotate-end-of-lines-using-python-and-matplotlib), but another method that gives something similar to your first option (albeit without the exact placement of the legend markers matching the positions of the associated lines) is:

```py
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

n=10
x = np.linspace(0, 1, n)
labels = [str(i) for i in range(len(x))]

for i in range(n):
    y = np.linspace(x[i], x[i], n)
    ax.plot(x, y, label=labels[i])

h, _ = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()

# sort the legend handles/labels so they are in the same order as the data
hls = sorted(zip(x, h, labels), reverse=True)

ax.legend(
    [ha[1] for ha in hls],  # get handles
    [la[2] for la in hls],  # get labels
    bbox_to_anchor=(1.04, 0, 0.1, 1),  # set box outside of axes
    loc="lower left",
    labelspacing=1.6,  # add space between labels
)

leg = ax.get_legend()

# expand the border of the legend
fontsize = fig.canvas.get_renderer().points_to_pixels(leg._fontsize)
pad = 2 * (leg.borderaxespad + leg.borderpad) * fontsize
leg._legend_box.set_height(leg.get_bbox_to_anchor().height - pad)
```

This is heavily reliant on the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43439132/1862861) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46710546/matplotlib-expand-legend-vertically).